# How to fix this problem on your phpmailer send method when importing the external libraries to send email?

Tags: php, forms, email, pdf, phpmailer

I am having this problem on my server logs and cant seem to figure this out and want to send an attached email with 3 pdf's to be on the email. But when im using phpmailer class and libraries to do this i get this from the logs

> Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '..\_lib\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer line 3.

```
<?php

require '..\_lib\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer;



$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('bankstatement', $_FILES)) {
    //Create a message
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->setFrom('info@acifinance', 'ACI Finance');
    $mail->addAddress('gcobani.mkontwana@agilelimitless.org.za', 'ACI Finance');
    $mail->Subject = 'ACI Finance Application Loan';
    $mail->Body = 'My message body';
    //Attach multiple files one by one
    for ($ct = 0, $ctMax = count($_FILES['bankstatement']['tmp_name']); $ct < $ctMax; $ct++) {
        //Extract an extension from the provided filename
        $ext = PHPMailer::mb_pathinfo($_FILES['bankstatement']['name'][$ct], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        //Define a safe location to move the uploaded file to, preserving the extension
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['bankstatement']['name'][$ct])) . '.' . $ext;
        $filename = $_FILES['bankstatement']['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bankstatement']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            if (!$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename)) {
                $msg .= 'Failed to attach file ' . $filename;
            }
        } else {
            $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        }
    }
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $msg .= 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Message sent!';
    }
}
?>


// HTML code
 <fieldset>
                                SELECT A pdf FILE TO UPLOAD
                                <br>
                                
                                 <label>ID </label><br>
                                <input type="File" name="id" id="id" accept=".pdf">
                                
                                <br>
                                <label>Bank Statement </label><br>
                                <input type="File" name="bankstatement" id="bankstatement" accept=".pdf">
                                <br>
                                <label>Pay Slip </label><br>
                                <input type="File" name="payslip" id="payslip" accept=".pdf">
                                <br>
                                <input type="Submit" id="btnNow" class="btn apply-btn mt-30" name="button" value="APPLY NOW">
                                </fieldset>
```

Comment: Try with :

require '../_lib/vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: @ImranKhan still do they same thing just check my logs and refresh them. funny part i do have these libraries from this path.

Comment: Why not take a look at the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) page to see how it is done?

Comment: You shouldn't use backslashes in web development to point to files/directories. These only works on windows systems and will fail when switching to an unix based server.

Comment: Both the `require` and `use` statements are wrong – look at how all the PHPMailer examples do it, and the readme that @brombeer pointed you at.